# Unable to change the look on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding, modern-pages

Any tricks to get to change the look for modern pages?

Recently migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Online, due to this we have a combination of sites that have modern and classic pages. I am unable to adjust the theme on Modern Pages, when I do here is an example of what I see

[image]

Have tried following the standard Microsoft Guides:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-look-of-your-sharepoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818
I do not have the option to get to the modern settings.

Comment: Modern themes will only appear if you are on the modern pages.  You can create a new page and then click Setting you will see as per the article from MS.  I understand that you are in the classic team site which means that you will have to use classic compose look provided.

Comment: So even though this example is a modern page (hero web part for evidence :-)), because it is on a classic site I am out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no OOB method to change the look for modern pages in SharePoint online.

It is by design.

The modern page is the new feature. And it will be improved in the future.

More reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages